# Shoud i need MongoDB profiler in case monitoring mongoDB using ELK stack + redis

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash, kibana, devops

I have just received a monitoring and analyzing MongoDB task.

Since detecting slow queries is my first priority so i took a look at fantastic MongoDB's feature: Profiler. I set a threshold of 40ms in order to evaluated slow queries.
And the logs for that detection stored in mongodb system.profile collection. And we have to carry out a query against system.profile collection to get logs in json formatted.

And if i do use do below following flow:

`MongoDB profiler => Redis (buffering) => Logstash (transform data) => Elastic (persistent storage) => Kibana(visualization)`.

So i have to write a script (`nodejs, python, bash`) in order to periodically carry out query against profiler collection and push them to redis? Or is there any way ease the process?

Can i tail the mongod log in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` and then manipulate directly the log using logstash?

Thanks for your time. :)